# Is there a free PDF editor that can handle XFA forms?

Tags: pdf, software-rec, free-software

I want to add an electronic signature to a PDF file which includes several XFA forms (probably because it was created with Adobe software on Windows), but every script/piece of software I try removes the forms with any change to the original file. Master PDF Editor is the only one I've found to work, but it inserts a watermark on the generated file, thus making it useless. Is there a free alternative?